# Why the name 'underscore' or 'lodash'?

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, lodash

Why are these libraries named after _ ?

Is there some significance behind it or the reason is **"Just because we can"**?

As far as i know, **underscore** and **lodash** do a lot of similar stuff. Also, both the names point to **_**

Even their variable names are **_**

So is there some relation of **_**  with the working of these libraries? Or its just a name?

Comment: Why is your name Dushyant? That's just a name. A short name, used for namespacing the library.

Comment: Well, there's a reason behind that too. Just wanted to know if there's a reason why both are named after _

Comment: lodash can be considered a fork of the _underscore_, a light version of underscore.

Comment: May be as per [this](https://twitter.com/tanaypratap/status/1216905984192339968?s=19) tweet, lodash is basically a word play on low dash i.e. underscore.
Why this?
coz a JS identifier's first character must be a letter, an underscore, or a dollar sign. 
Now, we all know that someone took the $ so the next most famous library took _

Comment: @Wajahath yeah, I got that part. But the main question was in the last line. Does "_" have any significance with what these libraries provide. Mostly its a "No".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## Lodash

From my understanding of the history of the two, `lodash` was meant as a lightweight replacement for underscore. So `lodash` is effectively a play on words on underscore - "low dash", what does a dash `-` look like when its a bit lower to the ground? `_` Why, an underscore of course

So that covers `lodash` in as much detail as it warrants.

## Underscore

Underscore's origin would only be a guess - but a guess I shall make.

"Back in the golden days" of Javascript, when the mighty `JQuery` reigned supreme, small (at the time) utility libraries started emerging - but one thing we didn't have at the time (or wasn't well known) was simple constructs for import and requiring external libraries.

Very much like `JQuery` grouping all of its functionality under one giant `$` object - underscore (I am guessing) wanted the same. Why? Probably for brevity and that l33t factor. Especially in the days where most people were just including a bunch of script tags in the footer. If you were looking at utility library home page, what appeals to you more:

```
// totes l33t
_.map(a, function(e) { ... }

// pfft, no thanks grandpa
underscore.map(a, function(e) { ... }
```

But why `_`. Well after `$` its one of few cool short names left:

> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode
>   categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”,
>   “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”,
>   or “Letter number (Nl)”.

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation! For a non-native speaker it's hard to find out why "lodash" is called this way and why every function starts with a "_." Came over from Google when searching for this. Imo this explanation should find it's way to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash, please consider this.

Comment: @philomatic If you think it belongs, why not add it to Wikipedia yourself? It's a crowdsourced site, after all. Though personally I the above might be more relevant to the history of underscore.js rather than Lodash.