# lodash function's prefix

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm a noob so apologie if this question sounds stupid but why do people use _. before lodash function. I've seen people usually use _. like _.cloneDeep() for lodash function but sometimes they seem to use lodash function without anything like [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/02571387ff48f92a5195a152e31dbad04a0158ba/editor/components/post-visibility/label.js#L14). Is there a reason ?

Comment: Basically because it looks cool. The same way that you can call Jquery by prefixing $, lodash is prefirex by _

The reason why they are not using _. in your link is that they are only importing one function from lodash, not the entire library

Comment: `_` is an object containing the called methods. [Back to school](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) ...

Comment: @Borjante It has nothing to do with looking cool... lol

Comment: @mhodges The reason for the name lodash seems to be for the cool factor (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006384/why-the-name-underscore-or-lodash/38048321#38048321) - to an extent anyway. However, you're right, its not really what this question is about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with how lodash is imported. Most of the time, people say `import * as _ from lodash`, so the entire library of lodash is referenced with `_`.

However, in the case you provided, they are just importing a single function from lodash by name (which works similarly to [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) - it will create a local variable with an identifier equal to that of the property name you are extracting), so there is no need for the `_` prefix.

What I prefer to do is something like this:

```
import { find } from 'lodash';
var _ = { find };

var item = _.find(.....);
```

And if you're using TypeScript, the `Partial` comes in handy here, like so:

```
var _:Partial<LoDashStatic> = {find};
```

That way you can get intellisense/type-safety without having to import the entire lodash library. Plus, your syntax doesn't change - it's always prefixed by `_.`

The reason I like it prefixed is so that I can guarantee the identifiers of imports will never conflict with any local identifiers I have. Also, I can always know at a glance whether something is a lodash method or not, without having to scroll up and look at the imports for that file.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the JavaScript environment you have set up. In some environments, your only option is to use the global underscore (`_`) object that has all the functions.

When using a run time or compile time environment that supports ES6 Modules, you can import the functions one at a time like this

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';
```

or this

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
```

There is even an [ES6 Module for each function](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized) and [other package formats as well](https://github.com/lodash/lodash#module-formats).

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep';
```

The ES6 Module options can help you make a smaller bundle for your app.

The first two samples - both of which are equivalent - rely on [tree shaking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking) to compile a smaller bundle.

In the third example we are only including the functions that we need. However, we will need to `npm install --save lodash.clonedeep` for each function that we want to use.

Comment: "The ES6 Module options can help you make a smaller bundler for your app". I think this only applies with bundlers that do tree shaking, right? I don't think it happens by default

Comment: If you import from the *one function per module* modules, you will by definition have decreased your bundle without relying on tree shaking.

Comment: Ahh, derp - I don't know why I didn't see that.. I was thinking you just said `import cloneDeep from 'lodash'`. Yes, you are correct - my mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I updated my answer to clarify the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The key there is this line:

`import { find } from 'lodash';`

In that case they are "extracting" one function from lodash and assigning it to a variable `find`.

This is fine if you only need a function or two from lodash. But if you need several, this technique gets a little cumbersome.